# Multiple files with different names? Generate unique id?

Tags: javascript, dropzone

I really need to identify the files on the Front End by unique id to avoid problems when the user uploads two files with the same name.
This works fine when I use one file, "datetime_filename.extention" which is great.

However if I move the rename line to the RenameFile property a new date is generated when a file is dropped which is logical, but this is causing some problems (when I call remove method, the file to be deleted always comes with the last date which is wrong if I delete some old file).

Some people tell me to do a Dictionary, some other to handle an Array of files, but I'm not really sure how to do that.

Any idea? (I know there are some simple fixes with PHP but we are not allowed to use it).

SCRIPT:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    let newname = new Date().getTime() + '_';
    var x = null;

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        const Drop2 = new Dropzone("div#myAwesomeDropzone", {url: "/Article/UploadFiles",

        paramName: "file",
        maxFiles: 6,
        maxFilesize: 1200,
        maxFileHeight: 840,
        maxFileWidth: 840,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        parallelUploads: 6,
        renameFile: function (file) {
            //let newname = new Date().getTime() + '_'; //FUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
            x = new File([file], newname + file.name);
            return x.name;
        },

            init: function () {

            this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {

                if (file.name.length > 100) { 

                    alert("Filename cant have more than 12 characters ");
                    this.removeFile(file);
                    var fs2 = new FormData();
                    fs2.append('file', x);
                    fs2.append('fileguid', '@Model.ImageGuid');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("Remove")',
                        data: fs2,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false
                    });
                }

                this.on("thumbnail", function (file) {

                    if ((file.height > this.options.maxFileHeight && file.width > this.options.maxFileWidth) || (file.height > this.options.maxFileHeight) || (file.width > this.options.maxFileWidth))
                    {
                        alert("Image max size allowed is 840 x 840");
                        this.removeFile(file);
                        var fs1 = new FormData();
                        fs1.append('file', x);
                        fs1.append('fileguid', '@Model.ImageGuid');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '@Url.Action("Remove")',
                            data: fs1,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false
                        });
                    }
                });

                this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {

                    alert("The maximum amount of files was exceeded");
                    this.removeFile(file);
                    var fs3 = new FormData();
                    fs3.append('file', x);
                    fs3.append('fileguid', '@Model.ImageGuid');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("Remove")',
                        data: fs3,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false
                    });
                });

                formData.append("file", x);
                formData.append("fileguid", '@Model.ImageGuid');

            });

            this.on("removedfile", function (file) {

                if (file.status == 'success') {

                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append('file', x);
                    fd.append('fileguid', '@Model.ImageGuid');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("Remove")',
                        data: fd,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
            <div style="font: 1.1em 'Source Sans Pro';">
            <div class="wrapper" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
                <div class="upload-console">
                    <div class="upload-console-body">
                        <div class="upload-console-drop">
                            <div class="dropzone-previews" style="border-style:dashed; border-color:#29d; border-radius: 5px;">
                                <div class="dropzone" id="myAwesomeDropzone" style="border: none;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="dz-default dz-message" style="background-image: none;">
                                        <img src="~/Areas/PalermoContents/Icons/cloud.png" style="cursor: pointer !important; width: 216px; height: 144px;" />
                                        <br />
                                        <span class="upload-console-header" style="font:weight:bold; font-size:26px; color:#646C7F;">Drag and Drop Images:</span>
                                        <br />
                                        <span style="color:rgb(133,133,133)"> Drop images here or click to Upload.</span>
                                        <br />
                                        <img src="~/Areas/PalermoContents/Icons/browse-btn.png" style="cursor: pointer !important; margin-top: 10px;" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="text-align: center;">

                                <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 5px 0 0 0; color:#646C7F"> Maximum upload image size: <b>1000MB.</b></p>
                                <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 5px 0 0 0; color:#646C7F"> Maximum Quantity per images Upload: <b>10.</b></p>
                                <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 5px 0 0 0; color:#646C7F"> Supported images Type:</p>
                                <p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px; color:rgb(133,133,133)"> (.PNG,.JPG,.GIF,.JPEG) </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you post a working version in a Codepen or similar tool?

Comment: oh i forgot to tell, this is MVC. on my controller i create a new GUID (Constructor), my metods Upload and Remove are methods just as it is.